# How to create a list and filter out row from another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I know this question has been asked before, but every solution doesn't appear to work and gives me the same result. I am looking for insight into what I am doing wrong.

T_18_x2 and Tryp18_50 are large dataframes with different data (except for 2 columns). Specifically, each dataframe contains a column named 'Gene' that posses the same style sting (i.e. HSP90A_HUMAN). I would like to make a list from the Gene column in T_18_x2 to filter rows in Tryp18_50 with the same string in the "Gene" column.

My issue is that the output is simply an empty dataframe. I think it is the string (y2) because the output of this list is duplicates of the strings in the column. I am not sure why this is happening either.
[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQedi.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

input:

```
y2 =T18_x2['Gene'].astype(str).values.tolist()
T18 = Tryp18_50[Tryp18_50['Gene'].isin(y2)]
T18
```

output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xJeX.png)

** I have also tried:

```
T18=Tryp18_50[pd.notna(Tryp18_50['Gene']) & Tryp18_50['Gene'].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(y2))]
```

with the output:

[2nd Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WbVk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I had two "Gene" columns in the first dataframe.